# Is there a program to turn 3D models into interactive pop-out of the screen anaglyph?

Tags: 3d, anaglyph-3d

We have 3D models from Autodesk Inventor that we can currently turn into 3D anaglyph models using an add-on program. This only works for still images though.

There is potential to do an animation and turn that video into an anaglyph but I dont have high hopes for it to be good quality and likely not popping out of the screen.

Is there another program available that can make an interactive 3D model that is a pop-out of the screen anaglyph?

Comment: Questions seeking software programs are off topic here.  Instead, describe the _programming problem_ you have and what you tried to solve it (including example code).

Comment: In general, generating 3-D videos of a scene involves capturing that scene with _more than one_ camera, with each lens in a slightly different position.

Comment: Peter O. It sounds like this is not the place to ask this question, though thank you, you just gave me an idea of how to solve the problem. Thanks!

I can animate the 3D model with two seperate animations slightly offset. Then put it through a video editing program overlaying the videos and working the colours to work with the Anaglyph glasses.